# Nil while unwrapping an Optional value but, during print the value exist

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, tableview, nsurl

I have a strange situation in my `TableViewController` when I want to set up picture in m cell. My cell class is:

> class TableViewCell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

/* OUTLETS */

@IBOutlet weak var pictureInRowOutlet: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var postDataOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titleOutlet: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization cod
} 

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}//end of class
```

> class MyTableView

```
class MyTableView: UITableViewController{

var data:[[String:String]]? // data load from serwer    

//code we don't need

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

// now I want to set up picture in row

let urlAdressPhoto = (data?[indexPath.item]["picture"])! 
// here, when I print urlAdressPhote I see correct value as String

cell.pictureInRowOutlet.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlAdressPhoto)!)!)
 // in this moment I recive an information about "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". 

return cell

}
```

Can somebody tell my why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: `NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlAdressPhoto)!)!` you force unwrap two optionals - that is causing the crash. Fix it.

Comment: but when I try to delete `!` in any case, Xcode recive me an error

Comment: read up on optionals and how to conditionally unwrap them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You force unwrap at least 3 different things. In this line,

```
let urlAdressPhoto = (data?[indexPath.item]["picture"])!
```

you force unwrap `(data?[indexPath.item]["picture"])` and you get lucky. It's not `nil`. You gambled and won.

Perhaps intoxicated by your success, you decide to double down...here, you force unwrap twice in a single statement:

```
UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlAdressPhoto)!)!)
```

Wow! That means that if `NSURL(string: urlAdressPhoto)` is `nil`, your program will crash. Or, if it is not `nil`, but the call to `NSData` is `nil`, then your program will crash.

The lesson is, and I can't say this often enough: **Don't use the `!` as a matter of convenience.** It blows up your code. While there are occasional good reasons to use it, most people use it because they are too lazy to unwrap. And then they get the `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

I would venture that that is the most common Swift-related question on Stack Overflow. There must be about 10 questions a day related to that error message, and it is all because people insist, for reasons that are totally beyond me, on using `!`.

Try this:

```
guard let urlAdressPhoto = (data?[indexPath.item]["picture"])
    , let url = NSURL(string: urlAdressPhoto)
    , let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else { 
        print("Something failed to unwrap..."); return cell
    }

cell.pictureInRowOutlet.image = UImage(data: data)
```